# Time Spent by User on a Particular WebPage/Form - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I want to track the time spent by a user on a particular Django webpage and upload it to the admin. Can this be done with the Python time module? If so how can I do it? I am also open to other suggestions, but since I am a beginner I would prefer them to be simple.

Thanks in advance.